# Horizontal ScrollView Stopping in the middle

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I have created a horizontal scrollview in swift with 3 view controllers and it almost works fine except for one thing. When I scroll between view controllers, it is possible for half of one view controller to take up one half of the screen and the next view controller in the other half. I was wondering if there was any way to prevent this so that the view controllers do not get "stuck" halfway and that there will always be only one view controller displaying on the screen.

-Also on a side note I have one left and one right swipe gesture within one of the viewcontrollers in this scrollview, and I noticed that after about 7-10 swipes,  the screen no longer responds to the swipe gestures(left, right). Any clues as to what could be solving this?

If anyone could answer or attempt to steer me in the right direction for solving one or both of these questions, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Two things. Turn on "isPagingEnabled" on your scrollview. This will give the behaviour you are looking for. And you should probably be using a UIPageViewController for this. (But scrollview is fine for now)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to enable pageing for your scrollview. You should be using something like

```
scorllView.isPagingEnabled = true
```

Then most importantly, you to make this paging work, each "page" in your scroll view must has equal width with your scroll view.